# .htaccess SEF rewrite issue with periods (dot) in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following set of rewrite rules works perfect until there is a period in the URL, in case a dot is present, a 404 not found error shows, there is something wrong. Removing the dot will make the code SEF url work but in this case there is no match in the database. I saw many solutions but wasn't able to figure this out, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks! : )

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5 [L]
```

Here are the examples of URLs, the original and after SEF rewrite:

> index.php?lang=en&co=Florida&ct=Miami&st=Co.%20Op.%20City%20Blvd%20nr.%20801&zip=10475
>
> WORKS : /en/Florida/Miami_Beach/Euclid_Ave_801/zip-33139
>
> DOESNT: /en/New_York/Bronx/Co._Op._City_Blvd_nr._801/zip-10475

*whenever there is a dot in the url it will not work when there is no issue with comma, semicolon or other characters

Comment: what are you expecting the url to look like?

Comment: Give us examples of urls with dots, and without dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use PHP to process your url, like this :

In .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

In index.php :

```
$uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

And then explore the $uri array or change it into multiple vars then you don't have to modify your whole script :

```
foreach( $uri as $k => $v ){

    $_GET['p'.$k+1] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was in relation with another rule that caused part of the issue. Here is how we solved it, inspired by [Bob0t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799829/bob0t)'s answer:

this was part of the issue:

```
# require www prefix for all urls of ANY domain & for parked domains by Yatko.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]
```

changed it to:

```
# require www prefix for all urls of ANY domain & for parked domains by Yatko.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.yatko.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)\.(.*)$ $1|$2
```

and a bit of change in the PHP code:

```
foreach($_req as $rk => $rv){
        $_req[$rk] = str_replace("|", ".", $rv);
    }
```